# How do I convert date format to YYYY-MM-DD with SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, utc

I have an api return a date/time in UTC and want my database query to match this format. The date format I require is:

```
2015-04-16T13:41:00.000+0000
```

So far my query looks like this:

```
SUBSTR(To_Char(cast(booking_date as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC'), 0, 24) AS bd
```

Which returns:

```
16-APR-15 13.41.00.00000
```

The query is currently run in Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: What is the datatype of booking_date?

Comment: add another parameter to your to_char method. that can specify a desired date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#sthref408), you can include text literals in the date format by double-quoting them, and the rest of the date format elements are fairly standard:

```
to_char(cast(booking_date as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC',
  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"+0000"')
```

Quick demo:

```
select to_char(cast(sysdate as timestamp) at time zone 'UTC',
  'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ff3"+0000"') as utc_timestamp
from dual;

UTC_TIMESTAMP                    
----------------------------------
2015-04-16T16:07:53.000+0000
```